# Merge python logging handler output

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I am implementing `python.logging` for a project that relies on a 3rd-party software that also uses logging.

The issue is we want console output, and the logs from the two are getting double printed.  Is there a way to set up a handler to "combine" the output of sub-handlers?

```
import logging
import sys


def third_party_use():
    print_log = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout)
    print_log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    print_log.name = "SubPrintLog"
    print_log.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("SubPrintLog %(name)s - %(levelname)s: %(message)s"))

    third_party_logger = logging.getLogger("ThirdParty")
    third_party_logger.addHandler(print_log)
    third_party_logger.info("I don't want this to print twice")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_log = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout)
    print_log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    print_log.name = "MyPrintLog"
    print_log.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("MyPrintLog %(name)s - %(levelname)s: %(message)s"))

    logging.basicConfig(level=0, handlers=[print_log])
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    logger.debug("This shouldn't appear")
    logger.info("This should")
    logger.warning("This definitely should")

    third_party_use()

    logger.info("Just my stuff again")
```

yields:

```
MyPrintLog __main__ - INFO: This should
MyPrintLog __main__ - WARNING: This definitely should
SubPrintLog ThirdParty - INFO: I don't want this to print twice
MyPrintLog ThirdParty - INFO: I don't want this to print twice
MyPrintLog __main__ - INFO: Just my stuff again
```

Is there a way to set up `MyPrintLog` to not reproduce output from `ThirdParty` (assume we have no access to modify the configuration of `ThirdParty`.  I was hoping that the `propagate` flag would fix this problem, but it flows the other direction and we can't modify `ThirdParty`)

One solution that "works" is to effectively disable `MyPrintLog` when calling `ThirdParty`:

```
def turn_off_console():
    for idx, handler in enumerate(logger.root.handlers):
        if handler.name == "MyPrintLog":
            old_level = handler.level
            handler.setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
            return idx, old_level


def turn_on_console(handle_index, level):
    logger.root.handlers[handle_index].setLevel(level)
```

And then wrapping each access to the third party:

```
    idx, old_level = turn_off_console()
    third_party_use()
    turn_on_console(idx, old_level)
```

Which yields the correct output:

```
MyPrintLog __main__ - INFO: This should
MyPrintLog __main__ - WARNING: This definitely should
SubPrintLog ThirdParty - INFO: I don't want this to print twice
MyPrintLog __main__ - INFO: Just my stuff again
```

But, that means I have to toggle the logger every time, which is prone to error.

EDIT:::SOLVED

```
class NoThirdParty(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        return not record.name == "ThirdParty"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_log = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout)
    print_log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    print_log.addFilter(NoThirdParty()) # Do Not Reproduce Third Party!
    print_log.name = "MyPrintLog"
    print_log.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("MyPrintLog %(name)s - %(levelname)s: %(message)s"))
    
    ...
```

yields:

```
MyPrintLog __main__ - INFO: This should
MyPrintLog __main__ - WARNING: This definitely should
SubPrintLog ThirdParty - INFO: I don't want this to print twice
MyPrintLog __main__ - INFO: Just my stuff again
```

[This Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54989300/gurobi-and-gurobipy-doubled-output-console-when-using-python-logging) solves the same problem by applying the filter to the 3rd Party logger

Comment: Seems a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729268/log-messages-appearing-twice-with-python-logging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class NoThirdParty(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        return not record.name == "ThirdParty"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_log = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout)
    print_log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    print_log.addFilter(NoThirdParty()) # Do Not Reproduce Third Party!
    print_log.name = "MyPrintLog"
    print_log.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("MyPrintLog %(name)s - %(levelname)s: %(message)s"))
    
    ...
```

yields:

```
MyPrintLog __main__ - INFO: This should
MyPrintLog __main__ - WARNING: This definitely should
SubPrintLog ThirdParty - INFO: I don't want this to print twice
MyPrintLog __main__ - INFO: Just my stuff again
```

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to say how to avoid duplicates using `logging` features, but if you decide to do something like

```
idx, old_level = turn_off_console()
third_party_use()
turn_on_console(idx, old_level)
```

you might find [`contextlib.contextmanager`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager) useful, as it allows you to create context manager by doing

```
import contextlib
...
@contextlib.contextmanager
def disengage_logger():
    idx, old_level = turn_off_console()
    try:
        yield (idx, old_level)
    finally:
        turn_on_console(idx, old_level)
```

and then use it following way

```
with disengage_logger():
    third_party_use()
```

Comment: That is extremely useful, thank you.  

I was able to solve the actual problem with `filter`, but this is a handy tool to keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

You've added the `print_log` handler to both your `ThirdParty` logger and the root logger (via the `basicConfig()` call), which is why you end up with doubled output. Just don't add the handler to the `ThirdParty` logger. Handlers of ancestor loggers are called to handle events, in the default case.

No need for anything fancier like filters or setting `propagate`, from what I can see.

Comment: The `ThirdParty` logger represents a logger created by another package (over which I have no control).  

I was able to mock up the behavior using the example above.

Comment: @planetes42 Unless the third-party library is badly-behaved, the application should always have control over the logging configuration. If you're saying that the above just mocks up what the third-party library does internally, then fair enough - but you should in that case definitely log a bug against it, if you can. Point them to this: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging-for-a-library

Comment: Thank you @Vinay.  I was able to confirm with the Third Party that "there is currently no way to generate log information without also printing to console" within their app.  

They agree that is an undesired pattern and are going to fix it in the future.  

For now, the Filter is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try stopping propagation from the sub-logger

```py
third_party_logger.propagate = False
```

Comment: I believe I would have to set that flag on the `ThirdParty` logger, which I don't have access to, correct?

Comment: Also -- I do want to `propagate` the information from the log to other `Handlers`, just not the handler going to `stdout`.  I believe the `Filter` method is going to work well

Comment: Yes, clarified the answer. I missed the requirements that you cannot modify it. Anyway loggers can also be fetched using `logging.getLogger("ThirdParty")`. That will return a reference to the same logger.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  However, I do want the logger to propagate to other loggers, just not the `stdout` one.